# How to shift cells in a different worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I'm working in excel sheet "A" which has all the data.
Sheet "B" accesses sheet "A" in a periodic manner, for example `cell A1 (in sheet "B") = "A!C1"` (in sheet "A") How can I increment the reference in sheet "B" by constant number of columns in sheet A (example 3 columns) so that I can get something like `cell A1 = "A!F1"`, `cell A2 = "A!I1"`, `cell A3 = "A!L1"` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get an answer to use the volatile [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) but resist the urge. The non-volatile [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) can perform the task just as easily.

In A1,

```
=INDEX(A!$1:$1, 1, (ROW(1:1)-1)*3+6)
```

Fill down as necessary. This will retrieve A!F1, A!I1, A!L1, etc as it is filled down.

Comment: I'm getting a #NAME? error, I've selected the table, the correct row number and I changed the row(1:1) to column(1:1) because I fill horizontally.